# iOS: Getting 415(unsupported media type) error while consuming RESTFUL web service using NSUrlConnection

Tags: ios, rest

I am trying to a restful web service in iOS application using NSUrlConnection. I am using below code to format the json string and then send over to a restful web service. But I am getting '415(unsupported media type)' response in connectionReceiveResponse: method. Please tell me where I am going wrong here.

NSURL *urlLoginAuthentication= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.loginService/mp/api"];

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlLoginAuthentication];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.txtUserName.text, self.txtPassWord.text,nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password", nil]];

NSLog(@"Dict: %@",jsonDict);

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString);

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"contentType"];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"dataType"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
NSLog(@"jsonData: %@",jsonData);

self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You receive HTTP status code 415 when the Content-Type you sent with the request is not a support type. Looking at the code, you are incorrectly setting the Content-Type header. This line:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"contentType"];
```

should be

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```